# Get Exception type from an exception

Tags: c#

I have a application to connect SAP with an RFC call and I need to show a notification to the user when connection failed while try to establish the RFC call with SAP. And I'm getting the following exception.

```
{
    SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException: 
    LOCATION    CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode
    ERROR       partner '151.9.39.8:8010' not reached
    TIME        Wed Jul 16 10:32:05 2014
    RELEASE     720
    COMPONENT   NI (network interface)
    VERSION     40
    RC          -10
    MODULE      nixxi.cpp
    LINE        3286
    DETAIL      NiPConnect2: 151.9.39.8:8010
    SYSTEM CALL connect
    ERRNO       10060
    ERRNO TEXT  WSAETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out
    COUNTER     2
}
```

And by using this exception I need to notify the user. But how can I identify whether it is a `SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException` or not because I'm handling other exceptions too. Is there any way to get the type of the exception without concatenating the above exception string.

In my try catch block 
I'm currently doing this but it is not working.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{  
    if (ex.ToString().ToLower() == "rfccommunicationexception")
    {
        MessageError = "RFC error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `RfcCommunicationException` not available in an assembly somewhere? Why not just do `catch (RfcCommunicationException ex)`?

Comment: sorry for that.. I was in a tight situation

Comment: no need to say sorry @tarzanbappa :)

Comment: Visual Studio is telling me that: The type "SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException" is not defined. Got any ideas?

Comment: did you add references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `is`

For example:-

```
catch (Exception exception )
{  
    if (exception is SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException)
    { 
       ////Your code
    }
}
```

Or as Resharper suggest its better to catch specific exception as shown below :-

```
catch(SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException)
{
    // Your code    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Catch the exception explicitly:

```
catch(SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException)
{
    // RFC exception
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // All other exceptions
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best approach to this is to have multiple catch blocks:

```
try
{
   // your code
}
catch(RfcCommunicationException rfcEx)
{
  // handle rfc communication exception
}
cathc(Exception ex)
{
  // handle other exception
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
// Catch the exception
catch(exception e)
{
    // Check if the type of the exception is an RFC exception.
    if(e is SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException)
    {

    }
    else // It is not an RFC exception.
    {

    }
}
```

Or you could try to `catch` each exception separately like below:

```
catch(SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException exception)
{

}
catch(exception e)
{

}
```