# The type "SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException" is not defined

Tags: vb.net, sap-dotnet-connector

I have already found this: [Get Exception type from an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772736/get-exception-type-from-an-exception)

The given answer is exactly what I had in my code, but the type **"SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException"** is not defined in my SAPConnector as it seems.

The relevant piece of code looks like this:

```
Public Sub RFC_Connect()
    Dim rfcFunctionStandort As IRfcFunction
    Try
        'Build RFC-Connection
        RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(New SAP_Connect)
        rfcDestination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("SomeDestination")
    Catch ex As SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcCommunicationException
        'Connection Refused
        'Set the app to Offline-Mode
    Catch ex As Exception
        frmHauptmenue.txtEdit.ErrorLog(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

When running this without the first catch-statement it throws the "RfcCommunicationException" stated above.

```
Public Sub RFC_Connect()
    Dim rfcFunctionStandort As IRfcFunction
    Try
        'Build RFC-Connection
        RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(New SAP_Connect)
        rfcDestination = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("SomeDestination")
    Catch ex As Exception
        frmHauptmenue.txtEdit.ErrorLog(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The import of the connector itself is done and working:

```
Imports SAP.Middleware.Connector
```

Answer (score 1):

The SAP NCo3 consists of two DLLs: sapnco.dll and sapnco_utils.dll. Did you perhaps reference only one of these in your Visual Studio project? In my project I have no problem using the RfcCommunicationException!

In fact: Visual Studio shows that RfcCommunicationException is exported from the sapnco_utils assembly. That gives me another idea: sapnco.dll is basically platform-independent, but sapnco_utils.dll contains unmanaged C/C++ modules and therefore needs to be used in a platform-dependent way (either 32bit/x86 or 64bit/x64)! So two other possible causes of your problem might be:

- You have defined your Visual Studio project as "Mixed platform"
- You have defined your Visual Studio project as x86, but downloaded/installed the x64 version of NCo3, or vice versa (defined the project as x64 and downloaded x86 version).